# Displaying references

Tags: rust, dereference

I have this code here.

```
fn main() {
    // Assign a reference of type `i32`. The `&` signifies there
    // is a reference being assigned.
    let reference = &4;

    match reference {
        val => println!("Got a value via destructuring: {}", val),
    }
    match *reference {
        val => println!("Got a value via destructuring: {}", val),
    }
}
```

I was expecting to get a result like:

```
Got a value via destructuring: &4
Got a value via destructuring: 4
```

But I got

```
Got a value via destructuring: 4
Got a value via destructuring: 4
```

Could someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 6):

When using the `{}` syntax in a format string, you are requesting that the value be formatted using its implementation of the [`Display` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html). There is a built-in implementation for the primitive numeric types, which explains the case where you are formatting a number.

But what about a reference to a number?  Well, there is a built in blanket implementation for all references to types that implement `Display`: [`impl<T> Display for &T where T: Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html#impl-Display-for-%26T).  This implementation simply delegates to the referent's `Display` implementation, which is why there is no difference in the output.  (Note that [the same is true of `Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html#impl-Debug-for-%26T).)